# How should i do if i want to get CycledLeScanCallback use Android-Beacon-library

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon

As what title said, what should i do to get `CycledLeScanCallback`. I'm using `android-beacon-library` and i have some reason need to use its `CycledLeScanCallback`. Thanks in advance if you can help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CycledLeScanCallback` is part of the internal implementation of the Android Beacon Library, and is not designed for external use.  It is not part of the public API.

The library is open source, so you are welcome to use its internal classes.  But because they are not designed to be used this way, you will probably find it difficult to adapt to your use case, and you won't find much if any documentation.

If you still want to try, I would recommend building the library from source, and modifying the `CycledLeScanCallback` to suit your needs.  The class is designed to start and stop Bluetooth scanning for beacon detection purposes and get raw Bluetooth scan callbacks and provide their results to higher level code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer david. I also found it was used for internal class after saw your source code. So i'm ready to modify source code. Thanks :D